# Docker-compose error with service env_file

Tags: docker, environment-variables, docker-compose, dockerfile

I've been working on passing my sensitive data (credentials) to the docker container through a .env file. I'm using docker-compose and my docker-compose.yml file looks as follows:

```
 services:
   some-service:
     env_file:
       - .env
```

But when I try to do "docker-compose up", I get the below error:

```
 ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', service 'env_file' must be a mapping not an array.
```

My .env file has data like

id = 1234567890

pwd = my_pwd

Are there any indentation errors in my file? Any suggestions on how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not with the indentation. Seems like it is working now. I actually had to mention the version and build path(they were missing in my initial yml file). So the final docker-compose file would look like as follows:

```
version: '3'
services:
  some-service:
    build: .
    env_file:
      - .env
```

or if you want you can associate it with a specific image name as:

```
version: '3'
services:
  some-service:
    build: .
    image: image_name:image_version
    env_file:
      - .env
```

Hope this will help someone who run into the same issue

Comment: Not including the version (which your question originally included) changes you to v1 syntax where your indentation level was incorrect.

Comment: @BMitch ok. So, the default version is 1 if you don't mention any?

Comment: Yes. And the version 1 syntax is just services with everything indented back a level.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this is a problem with your YAML structure. It might be a missing space before your `- .env` or the missing service name. Try this:

```
services:
  some-service:
    env_file:
      - .env
```

If you only use one environment file, you can also write:

```
services:
  some-service:
    env_file: .env
```

See: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#env_file

Comment: what could be a valid value for some-service? I used "environment" and it gives me below error now. ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.environment.env_file contains ["a.env"], which is an invalid type, it should be a string, number, or a null

Comment: Not sure about this. Although it might not be the problem, I wouldn't call the service 'environment', was this is a reserved keyword inside docker-compose. You can call it whatever makes sense to identify your service, it's just a name. Can you show your new configuration? I can't see where this letter 'a' in ["a.env"] comes from.

Comment: oh sorry. that 'a' in a.env has shown up because later I changed the .env filename to a.env just to explore around if that's the issue. but seems like file name has nothing to do with the error.

Comment: Can't see any problem with my suggestion. It looks just like in the documentation. Therefore, could you please show your current configuration and the whole error?
By the way, the content of your .env file could be problematic as well, as the scheme needs to be like this: `VAR=hello` (see more information in the documentation linked in my answer).

Comment: Try with the full path.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. i've posted my answer--please refer

Answer (score 0):

```
ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', service 'env_file' must be a mapping not an array.
```

The error says that docker-compose believes `env_file` is the name of your service rather than a setting on a service. This indicates you have not correctly indented the `env_file` section to be within a service. YML syntax is white space sensitive, so double check the indentation on your lines. If you can't find the error with your indentation, please include the full docker-compose.yml file in your question, indented exactly as it is in your file, for us to assist further.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i've posted my answer--please refer